# Microcontroller information transfer to Android application

Tags: microcontroller

I wanted to do a project on bus tracking (GPS) through an Android application, therefore in order to do so: I need to install GPS module in bus along with microcontroller so that GPS fetches the bus location and sends it to micro controller.

We are also building an Android app so that anyone can access the bus location. **How do I send information to an Android app from the microcontroller?**

I heard about Bluetooth but it's irrelevant in this discussion.

Comment: I am confused. One solution is to run the Android app on a mobile phone which contains GPS. In that case, there is nothing else needed. Is the Android app running on something which does not have GPS? What is making "Bluetooth ... irrelevant in this discussion"? Why can't the Android platform use Bluetooth? Please explain more about your requirements and assumptions.

Comment: @gbulmer op is talking about two things. Gps tracking a bus, and user facing android app. Separate stages.

Comment: @passerby - That is a reasonable assumption. However, a simple way to build the entire system is to put Android phones, with GPS on the bus. Run an Android application on it. Send the bus position to a shared service, at appropriate times. For example after moving an 'interesting' distance, or an interesting change such as arriving at a bus stop, or sitting still for a while. SO where did the MCU come from?

Comment: We made one in J2ME on a older cellphone. It was cumbersome to manage the phones on the busses so we went with a ODB2 GPS unit and fetch the data from the tracking service to feed into our mobile app.

Comment: @gbulmer the tyical assumption that discrete modules and a microcontroller would be the best solution. And it might, in a mass produced product. But like I agree with you, proliferation of ultra cheap embedded loaded linux-y platforms (C.E.L.L. P.hones for short) makes them better for one off/proof of concept/prototyping. If it wasn't for lack of gpio or broken out busses on them, microcontrollers as a hobbyist platform would die quickly /rant.

Comment: That or OP is being constrained to project rules requiring a microcontroller. Both are equally plausible.

Comment: @Passerby - "If it wasn't for lack of gpio or broken out busses on them, microcontrollers as a hobbyist platform would die quickly", sounds like a "kickstarter project" to me :-) I have now read your answer, and I agree. For this application, a mobile phone is hard to beat, and that is what I was getting at. A mobile phone is a programmable device with on-board GPS, cellular modem, battery power supply, on-board battery charger with a non-proprietary connector ... . AFAICT, the solutions needs no other services or hardware. Once OP answers my questions, we may know more.

Answer (score 2):

For remote tracking of a car over a wide area, the only practical solution is a cellular modem. Gsm or cdma modules are available. They require service via a cellular provider.

Honestly, the proliferation of cheap (under 25 on sale) android cellphones provide all you need for this. Each one is cheaper than most cellular modules (let alone combined with gps and microcontroller costs), provide battery backup, multiple debugging interfaces (lcd, usb, wifi), have gps, standard power connector, etc. And can be easily programmed. And allow a level of abstraction from the specific hardware as most simple android app code around gps does not need porting.

At that point, in either case, they speak with a web server on your end. And both require not much signal/bandwidth to work. With prepaid cell services you could be talking cents a day per device service wise.

Comment: Agreed, implement the entire thing on a cheapo android phone with a data plan, then it is just simple Java programming and making sure the phone is kept on charge by one of the bus's "cigarette lighter" sockets.